# npmrc - Freeze lock file?

Tags: npm

When using Yarn, you can freeze changes to the lock file by specifying `install.frozen-lockfile true` in .yarnrc file. How do I achieve this with npm's package-lock.json in .npmrc file? Using yarn is not an option.
 I know we can use the command `npm ci` to use the lock file during install to maintain package versions, but how can I make it so that npm will never modify the lock file (currently if you were to use `npm install`, the lock file will be modified).

Comment: You can see the `.npmrc` options [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html) and the `install` options [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).